# Reading text file in C++ and parse the values into vectors

Tags: c++, string, vector

I have a text file containing some values like this:

```
John Doe 25 28 35 50 
Jane Doe 30 10 31 76 89 
John Roe 12 34 54
```

So, I read the file with the following program:

```
vector<string> lines()
{
  vector<string> lines; 
  string line;

  ifstream myfile("textfile.txt");

  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    while (getline(myfile, line))
     {
        lines.push_back(line);
     }
    myfile.close();
  }
  else 
  {
    cout << "Unable to open file";
  }

  return lines;
}
```

As you I am able to read the content line by line ... so far so good.

Then, I am iterating the `lines()` trying to read the names and the numerical values as well:

```
for (auto line : lines()) {
    string buf; // Have a buffer string
    stringstream ss(line); // Insert the string into a stream
    vector<string> tokens; 
    while (ss >> buf){
        tokens.push_back(buf);
    }
    string name = tokens[0] + " " + tokens[1];

    vector<string> names; // names holder vector
    names.push_back(name);

    vector<string> numbers;
    for (auto token : tokens){
        // pseudo code
        // if token is not a name then add to the numbers vector

    }
    // do something else

 }
```

Comment: Try using OOP. That will simplify your problem.

Comment: @Nabin Care to elaborate?

Comment: You want to know how to check if a string is an integer, and/or parse the string into integer? Is target vector of integers still going to store in strings, or you want `vector<int>`?

Comment: If he had used object to store using fstream.write((&obj, sizeof(obj)) then he could have retrieved the whole object and thus would be easy. Isn't it?

Comment: @Nabin No. That doesn't work. You can't assume the memory layout of an object is the same between compilers, or even the same compiler in a different mode. Also if the class contained virtual functions, this will just totally break. The OOP approach would be to have serialize functions or stream operators.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out how to do that. I do iterate the tokens and check if it's a number e.g.

```
for (auto token : tokens){

        // if token is an Int32 then add to the number vector
        if (isInt32(token)){
            numbers.push_back(atoi(token.c_str()));
        }
    }
```

**Note:** the isInt32 is a small func that checks if regex [0-9] matches the string input

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really see a question being asked here. But you should move your names vector outside of that loop otherwise it will always only hold one element. And will the first two tokens always be the full name? What about a middle initial? I really love this sort of thing (parsing), and I hope you come back with a question.